# Create two documents with TCPDF

Tags: pdf-generation, tcpdf

I am generating long PDF document with TCPDF.
What I want is to create two versions of this document - one with all pages and one with only 5 pages.
But when I call Output whole document is destroyed and I cannot call Output once again - how to create another document?

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem - I've made instance of Object

```
$short_pdf= clone $this;
```